# Java SSL picks wrong cert, ignores key usage

Tags: java, ssl, certificate

I have a client/server which is using SSL to communicate.

The keystore JKS in the client contains *two* certs with different key usage. Cert 1 is for SSL communication and cert 2 is for signing data:

1. One cert has `KU=keyEncipherment,digitalSignature, EKU=clientAuth`
2. One cert has `KU=nonRepudiation,digitalSignature`

When I run with this, it picks the first one (correct!). If I remove the first cert from the JKS, it picks the cert with `nonRepudiation` when connecting to the server (wrong!?).

That makes no sense to me as nonRep should never be used like that afaik.

So, what can I do to fix this, how can I make Java SSL pick only certs with sane key usage?

Btw, JDK1.70_21 on Windows. The code I'm using is standard stuff. Just getting default keymanagers etc

Comment: What Java Runtime are you taking about (manufacturer, platform & version)?

Comment: JDK1.70_21 on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, your second certificate may have the `nonRepudiation` key usage extension, but as far as I know, this doesn't make it invalid for client-certificate use. The TLS specification doesn't really say much about key usage on the client side, although technically, it uses a digital signature (so both your certs could be valid). Assuming `digitalSignature` is indeed required (which it is in practise, as far as I know), both your certs have it, so both your certs are suitable. The fact that one also has other key usages is a different matter.

In addition, `clientAuth` is not a key usage extension, but an *extended* key usage extension (or a Netscape extension). Your second certificate, lacking any extended key usage extension, leaves any extended key usage possible.

Secondly, the authors of the default `X509KeyManager` implementation in the JSSE made the choice of returning imperfect matches when perfect matches were missing. See [code comments](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/X509KeyManagerImpl.java#L317):

```
/*
* Return the best alias that fits the given parameters.
* The algorithm we use is:
* . scan through all the aliases in all builders in order
* . as soon as we find a perfect match, return
* (i.e. a match with a cert that has appropriate key usage
* and is not expired).
* . if we do not find a perfect match, keep looping and remember
* the imperfect matches
* . at the end, sort the imperfect matches. we prefer expired certs
* with appropriate key usage to certs with the wrong key usage.
* return the first one of them.
*/
private String chooseAlias(List<KeyType> keyTypeList, Principal[] issuers,
```

Hence, when the certificate with `keyEncipherment,digitalSignature,clientAuth` is missing, it will fall back on the other one.

It's an arguable choice, but it's not necessarily a bad one. There are implementations and deployments out there that are not necessarily 100% standard compliant, and where it's handy to be able to send something regardless of what your CA gave you. At the end of the day, it's not a massive risk since (a) it's really up to you to choose what you put in your keystore and (b) it's up to the server to check the key usage in all cases.

It seems quite odd to put a certificate that you wouldn't want to use for SSL/TLS usage in a keystore you set with the `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` property, or to build an `SSLContext` with it.

I'm not sure why you would put it in this keystore, but if you need that other certificate to be available for something else in your application, it's generally easier to place it in a different keystore.

Alternatively, you can implement your own `X509KeyManager` and override its `chooseClientAlias` method as required. In this case, I would create a class that delegates all the calls to the default `X509KeyManager` (obtained from a `KeyManagerFactory` with the default algorithm and initialised with your keystore), except `chooseClientAlias` where you'd check the key usage type before returning the alias. It's certainly feasible, but a bit more work than using two keystores.

For reference:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.3
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/NSS/nss_tech_notes/nss_tech_note3 (note that, as far as I'm aware, there is no standard requirement for there to be any Nescape Cert Type or Extended Key Usage extension for a client-certificate to be valid).

Comment: Thanks! Having one keystore with both certs is just to make it easier for the users. Just one file to mess around with and then pick the correct one based on keyUsage/extKeyUsage (or alias name).

Comment: Great find with the X509KeyManagerImpl comment there btw! Given the sheer amount of crypto related classes in Java, I kinda assumed there was an easier way to configure/build the manager w/o having to use internal classes or write it from scratch (which is a bit scary for obvious reasons).

Comment: Your main problem is that both certs are valid for client-certificate usage in my opinion. I would suggest letting the user specify the alias explicitly (you might need to write a small X509KeyManager that returns only that configured alias, but that shouldn't be too difficult).

Comment: Dropping `digitalSignature` from cert 2 makes this work as I want. Googling NR and DS, I get the impression that this is recommended. For [instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468127/x509-whats-the-difference-between-digital-signature-and-non-repudiation)