# Signing XML with XAdES-EPES in Java

Tags: java, xml, sign, xades4j

I'm currently working on some legal requirements for my country (electronic invoicing) but I'm stuck on the signing part, here the background:

1. The government provides every user with a .p12 certificate file
2. Once an XML is generated, it has to be signed with XAdES-EPES based on the previous mentioned .p12 certificate.

I don't really understand much about certificates and security artifacts, I found a java library called: [Xades4J](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j) however most of the examples mention a KeyStore and TSA (Which btw don't really understand what a TSA is), the scenario that I have seems very simple to use, but I believe most of the examples mentioned are far to complex.

Can anybody give me a hand about the concepts and/or provide with an example of how you can sign using XAdES-EPES having already a p12 file?

I saw some C# examples that I'll test too, thing is I'm mostly coding in Java.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A keystore is some kind of storage for one or more key(s) and related data; PKCS12, often abbreviated (like file extension) P12 or p12 and also called PFX, is an industry-standard keystore format that usually contains an encrypted private key with certificate or chain -- or if you prefer, a cert/chain with private key. Java crypto has supported PKCS12 as _a_ keystore format for a long time and just-released Java 9 makes it the default. TSA in this context is [Time Stamping Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping#Trusted_%28digital%29_timestamping).

Comment: Does your application will have a legal context in Spain? I ask that because then you have the propers tools to work this out.

Comment: Did you find out the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently, in the xades4j Github issues, there was a conversation around a scenario very similar to your requirements. Checkout this issue:

https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/issues/134

It includes example code using a p12 file for certificate/key.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the beginning.

KeyStore : In a simple concept it is where you store your certificates, before the signing process you have to select a certificate normally extracted from a KeyStore -> [Here you get a complete perspective about what is a keyStore.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202046/what-is-keystore)

TSA : Time Stamp Autoriry, this is an external entity, it have to be an official one if you need the government to accept your signatures. This will give you a timestamp mark and will add extra information to your previous signature securing that your certificate was valid and the signature was correct at that period of time. [Here is a close context to extend your information about signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47931395/9112160)

> Take in mind that XAdES-EPES is deprecated, you should use instead
>   XAdES-A (if you need periodical timestamping) or AdES-LTA.

In case and only in case that your application have a legal context in Spain you could use this tools to do what your needed: [Sing and validate signatures](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/127286/70399)

Hope this helps.